# Tweetstream and Rails - can't get any response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, tweetstream

I am using Tweetstream gem for Rails and keep getting stuck waiting for any update..

I basically do the example (with my oauth data etc. of course):

```
    require 'Tweetstream'

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = 'consumer_key'
  config.consumer_secret    = 'secret'
  config.oauth_token        = 'token'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'token_secret'
  config.auth_method        = :oauth
end

TweetStream::Client.new.sample do |status|
      puts "SOMETHING HERE?"
  puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

and nothing happens... the console is just waiting forever for anything to happen..

not even "SOMETHING HERE?" is getting printed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess and say you are putting this in an initializer? The gem doesn't work this way. TweetStream is an event-based library and has a different runtime profile from that of a Rails app.

You will need to run TweetStream side by side with Rails as a daemon process collecting the tweets, storing them on a DB and Rails will access that same DB.

Use Rails Runner (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) to run your TweetStream daemon on the context of Rails, this should give you access to the models.

Comment: the guess is on point! So just trying it in console wont' work either I presume?

Comment: No it won't. For example if you need to host this in, let's say Heroku, you will need to use a Procfile and run it with a worker side by side to rails:

`web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV \n
stream: bundle exec rails runner streaming.rb`

When using a Procfile, you could launch both locally by using foreman (`foreman start`)